# What's holidays entitlement for postdocs in the UK?

Tags: postdocs, job, united-kingdom

I applied for a postdoc position. In the job description, they mentioned that they offer a 30 days holiday plus bank holidays and Christmas closure. But when I received a formal offer, they mentioned this: "219 hours plus all customary and statutory bank holidays per holiday year". This means at most, 2 weeks per year? Am I missing missing? Is this common for postdocs in the UK?

Comment: Isn't a 8 hour day/40 hour work week customary in the UK? 219 hours for me in the US would sound like 219/40 = about 5 1/2 weeks or 27 working days; adding in some other holidays would easily bring that over 30.

Comment: Actually, "8" hour days includes a meal break. 219/30 = 7.3. So that sounds about right.

Comment: Yes, @BryanKrause is correct. Your contract will have a nominal number of working hours per day (probably 7.5), and so you need to do 219/(hours per day) to get the number of days' holiday. Then you additionally get all [bank holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays). 'Customary days' depend on local factors, but probably amount to any days between Christmas and New Year that aren't already holidays.

Comment: I think I wasn't seen it that way. Since they've mentioned my hours per day which 8.5, I thought that directly mentioned the number in days. I am applying from overseas, so I don't know about this stuff. Can you kindly answer the question with a general rule?

Comment: Probably 8.5 hours per day assumes 8 working hours and a 30 minute lunch break.

Comment: They've mentioned this "9am to 5:30 pm Monday through Thursday and from 9am to 4:3p pm on Fridays, with an hour for lunch daily". So, I think it's assumed in their calculations!

Comment: Right. So you're expected to work for 36 hours a week. 219/36 = 6 weeks' worth of leave = 30 days as promised. Plus bank holidays and customary days.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking you need to take a full 24 hours of vacation to get the day off?

Typically you take hours off for your working hours (I'm in the US but I can't really imagine this being different for the UK; also the math works out). So for a job as stated where you have a total of 36.5 hours of working time per week, 219 hours would then be exactly 6 weeks (aka 30 work days) of vacation, which you can take in whatever increments are suitable (say, 4 hours if you need just half the day, 7.5 hours for a full Tuesday, etc). There might be some limits on when this time can actually be taken to not conflict with certain job responsibilities, but given proper notice they should accommodate your requests.

It would be reasonable to clarify exactly how vacation hours are awarded and taken (I'd search on the university website for some regulations before asking someone about it) but the numbers stated seem like they fit with the "30 days" in the job description.

Comment: Sorry - I had a typo in my comment above - the required hours are 36.5 hours per week so 219 hours is *exactly* 6 weeks.

Comment: @avid Whoops, took your word for it :)

Comment: Just two small notes: #1 a lot of UK universities will typically allocate vacation days per _academic_, not _tax_ year (so, September to September, rather than April to April). Unless you start in September, you are likely to see proportionately less days for the current year. #2 our system allows booking half and full days off (but no finer than that).